# AppEngine domain ownership failing

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl-certificate, google-search-console

Trying to upload a ssl certificate and private key file through the console and using sdk returns with the error message that i am not the administrator/owner for the domain(s), even though i have verified the domain(s) using webmaster and the owned websites are listed in the response.

```
gcloud app ssl-certificates create --certificate=tls.crt --display-name=harambee --private-key=tls.key
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.ssl-certificates.create) User [yournamehere@harambeecloud.com] does not have permission to access app [app-project-id] (or it may not exist): Caller is not authorized to administer this certificate. You must be a verified owner of the certificate's domain(s) [**www.harambee.mobi**, **www.harambee.co.za**, **harambee.co.za**, **www.vulindlelejozi.mobi**, **vulindlelejozi.co.za**] to create, modify, or delete this resource. Your authorized domain(s) are [**harambeecloud.com**, **harambee.mobi**, **harambee.co.za**]. If you own the certificate domain(s), you can obtain authorization by verifying ownership via the Webmaster Central portal: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification.